# Debian embedded I/O ports access privileges

Tags: debian

I'm running a Debian 8.7 minimal install on a MOXA embedded hardware.

To access my digital ports, every time I log on I need to do (otherwise I get errors reading or writing into the ports):

```
$ sudo chmod o+rw /dev/dio
```

Is there any way to make this change permanent between reboots?

Comment: This may be of use: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147494/how-can-i-set-device-rw-permissions-permanently-on-raspbian